# Java android sort List java object by double

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections

[image]Hi I have a List java object and one field is Double distance and I want to sort my list by this field. And It not works corretly.

I do this :

```
Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<AdapterRooteEntity>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(AdapterRooteEntity o1, AdapterRooteEntity o2) {
        // return o1.getAddress().compareTo(o2.getAddress());
        // return Double.compare(Tools.distance(o1.getLat(),
        // gps.getLatitude(), o1.getLon(), gps.getLongitude() ),
        // Tools.distance(o2.getLat(), gps.getLatitude(), o2.getLon(),
        // gps.getLongitude() ));
        return Double.compare(o1.getDistance(), o2.getDistance());
    }
});
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work correctly, what is the issue?

Comment: what is the problem with that code?

Comment: @kapsym I put a screen after sort by distance. I don't know why this sort a few objects not corretly

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ I get sort list with bugs

Comment: Your image is sorted in descending order... What bugs? What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can have your list sorted in a very simple way, by inserting each item in the correct position when you add them to the list.

```
public void sortedInsert(Item item){
    for ( int i = 0; i< yourList.size(); i++) {
        if ( item.getDistance() < yourList.get(i).getDistance()){
            yourList.add(i, item);
            return;
         }
    }
    // If the item hasn't been inserted
    yourList.add(item);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure  `o1.getDistance()` return `Double`, if not , use `Double.parse(o1.getDistance())` for `o1` and `o2`.